# How can I convert UITextField into Double?

Tags: swift, double, textfield

I wanted to get back into Swift and my basic knowledge I had is somewhat gone now from memory. I have a text field I want users to enter a price (Double) into, so I can take their input and enter that into an equation to compute a result that will be calculated by the app.

I have tried so many different ways of coding this, so many google searches, and have nothing that works. Constant errors. Below is a screenshot of the current code.

[Click To View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPQZ9.png)

Comment: Don't use an image of your code, copy your code instead.

Comment: Apologies for using an image, I am new to the site. Please don't vote this down, I hope it will help other people find solutions, as I have found mine here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a computed property:

```
var priceOne: Double? {
    return Double(priceOneLabel.text!)
}

var quantOne: Double? {
    return Double(quantOneLabel.text!)
}

@IBAction func calculateTotal(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let priceOne = self.priceOne, let quantOne = self.quantOne {
        let total = priceOne * quantOne
        // Update your total label...
    }
}
```

This gives you an `Optional<Double>` for the cases where the user didn't enter a valid numeric value into the label. You can check for nil and unwrap at time of use.

Comment: This solution helped, thanks so much! Appreciate the explanation as well.

Comment: If the answer work for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
let priceOne = Double(textfield.text!)
```

Comment: I attempted this however, I still was getting some yellow errors and suggested "fixes" that seemed rather odd by Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `priceOneLabel.text` instead `priceOneLabel`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that was an obvious error, however that was not the only problem with my code!